# Graphing equations not in the form of y= on Casio fx9860 II

Tags: graphing-functions, calculator

I have the Casio fx9860 II calculator, and I have been finding a way to input equations like $3x^2 +4y^2 -6x +8y -5 =0$ into the graphing program calculator.
However, it seems like all available kinds of equation supported are like $x= ,y= $ or inequalities. I want to graph equations that have $x$ and $y$ on the same side, like the equation above.

Thank you in advance

Comment: No way. I read the specification on their site. It's a great progress they can plot $x=g(y)$. You can use GeoGebra (it's free) or look here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+3x%5E2+%2B4y%5E2+-6x+%2B8y+-5+%3D0

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with the casio model, I know the 89 titanium at least has the ability to graph equations of the form $z=f(x,y)$, so you could graph the 3d wireframe model for $z=3x^2+4y^2-6x+8y-5$ and compare that to $z=0$ and look at interesection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a section called "CONICS" (There is on my CASIO CFX-9850G) and there is a option called $ax^2+ay^2+bx+cx+d$, but there is no other option, apart from to rearrange the equation to a form such as $\dfrac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$.

However, using graphing websites like [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/functions-graphing-calculator/3x%5E%7B2%7D%2B4y%5E%7B2%7D%E2%88%926x%2B8y%E2%88%925%3D0) might help.